# cross platform 2d game engine choices that need to be

Tags: android, c++, ios, 2d, game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2d game and I want to code once deploy everywhere (ios/droid/linux/windows).  Also, I don't want to pay $420 for a license; I need freedom.

So far, I have been looking at OpenFL, including HaxeFlixel (which builds on openFL), but its flash. Where is C++ in my life?

What other engines are like this?

Answer (score 1):

Definitly Cocos2d-x, it's cross platform and works smooth.
There are millions of code samples and hint over the net.

[Cocos2d-x | Cross Platform Open Source 2D Game Engine](http://www.cocos2d-x.org)

Answer (score 0):

- [UDK](http://www.unrealengine.com/udk/) provides one of the most powerful game engines, Unreal Engine 3. It supports iOS and Windows mainly. Its free for a limited commercial use but please check it again since it might have changed the values. Last time I checked, they allow to us to earn 5000/= for free and then pay a royalty fee of 99$ per year. Unrealscript is the main language and allows C++ DLL binding.
- Further, [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) engine provides powerful tools and portable to almost any platform. I am not familiar with its license. Please check it.
- I lately found this [Cafu engine](http://www.cafu.de/) which is powerful with many things. It is highly portable and currently it is written for OpenGL and OpenAL or FMOD and it is Open Source. Carsten is the man behind everything and he helps everybody in the forum, a very responsive person. Cafu is properly documented and totally C++ and Lua. Provides latest graphics since OpenGL is used. Bullet physics is currently integrated.
- [jMonkey](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) Engine 3 is also another option. Portability is given since it is java. Its not slow as I suspected. They have rewritten lot of internal code of java api to make it run efficiently. Netbeans with VCS support is there. Various plugins are also available.
- [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/) is a good graphics engine which is portable. But you will have to make your own game engine with it.
- [Torque3D](http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque-3d) and [ShiVa](http://www.stonetrip.com/) are some other engines i reviewed. Personally i do not see much in them. Try them out if you are interested. They are lacking proper documentation and support according to some people i have talked to.